# Type Of Merge Sort Confusion

Tags: c++, sorting

I am asked to write two types of merge sorts. One is a binary merge sort with time theta(n lgn) and a natural merge sort with time O(n lgn). I have searched everywhere to understand what each of them do. I am having trouble understanding the differences, I just need some explanation or examples would be great. I have written a merge sort but what I have is it a natural or binary merge sort?

```
bool compareElements(int i, int j)
{
    ++COMPARE_COUNT;
    //int *t = i;
     return i < j;
}
void merge(int values[], int left[], int right[], int middle, int total)  
{
int left_size = middle, right_size = total - middle;
int i = 0, j = 0;

// Loop through values array
for (int k = 0; k < total; k++)
{
    // If elements left on left and either no elements on right 
    // or left is larger than right, then use next left value
    if (i < left_size && (j >= right_size || left[i] <= right[j]))
    {
        values[k] = left[i];
        i++;
    }
    // else use next right value
    else
    {
        values[k] = right[j];
        j++;
    }
  }
}
void mergeSort(int values[], int n,bool result)  
{
if(result == false)
{
    if (n < 2)
    {
        return;
    }
    int middle = n / 2;
    int *left = new int [middle];
    int *right = new int [n - middle];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //COMPARE_COUNT++;
        if(compareElements(i,middle))        //(i < middle)
        {
            SWAP_COUNT++;
            left[i] = values[i];
        }
        else if(!compareElements(i,middle))
        {
            SWAP_COUNT++;
            right[i - middle] = values[i];
        }
    }
    mergeSort(left, middle,result);
    mergeSort(right, n - middle,result);
    merge(values, left, right, middle, n);
}
}
```

Comment: I did a web search for "binary merge sort" and didn't find any relevant hits. orlp's answer mentions a binary merge sort as a top down merge sort, but binary merge could also mean a 2 way (binary) bottom up merge sort, as opposed to a 4 way or higher k way (k > 4) bottom up merge sort. To answer your comment below, bottom up merge sorts (including natural bottom up merge sort) are iterative, not recursive. Also a natural merge sort may reverse descending sequences to turn them into ascending sequences, and ensure minimum run size >= 2 on the initial pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A binary merge sort has a very simple recursive definition: split the input array into two halves, sort the two halves using binary merge sort, merge the two halves into a sorted sequence. This is what you implemented.

A different version is a **bottom-up** merge sort. This first splits a sequence up into subsequences of length 1, and then starts merging them.

A *natural* merge sort has a different **first** step. It doesn't split the input sequence into halves, but into *runs*. A run is a sequence of elements that are increasing or decreasing. For example the following array:

```
0 1 4 2 3 9 8 7 5 2 1 3 4 2 4 3 4
```

Can be split into runs like this:

```
0 1 4 | 2 3 9 | 8 | 7 | 5 | 2 | 1 3 4 | 2 4 | 3 4
```

Where each run is is already ascending. Then you start merging runs as if you would in merge sort, except you merge **from the bottom up**.

The reason this is called a *natural* merge sort is that if your input is already (partially) pre-sorted, the algorithm will start to approach a O(n) best case performance.

Comment: Wow that was very helpful thank you, would the way I did be counted as a binary merge sort? It sounds like it may be.

Comment: @FastKid12 I edited that in, yes you've implemented binary merge sort, at least conceptually (I did not check your code for correctness).

Comment: Ah so natural would do all of the dirty work at once right?

Comment: @FastKid12 That is too vague a description to either refute or agree with. If the input is already sorted, then the natural merge sort will be done right after detecting the runs.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense

Comment: Just curios, bottom up and natural are not the same thing I assume right?

Comment: @FastKid12 You can have bottom-up merge sorts that aren't natural, but to my knowledge all natural merge sorts are bottom-up. Bottom-up means that you start from small sized arrays (either 1-sized or whatever size the runs are) and merge those, instead of splitting. Natural means that it runs faster for (partially) sorted inputs.

Comment: Ok great, I am in such a better position than I was earlier, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The more I read, a natural merge sort would be non recursive ?

Comment: @FastKid12 At the risk of sounding rude, I'm not here to hold your hand. I believe the question you originally asked has been sufficiently answered (which you can mark by clicking the checkmark next to the answer). If you get stuck again feel free to open a new question.